# Забиндить слушающий сокет на несколько адресов

Tags: c++, сокет

Как забиндить предназначенный для прослушки TCP-сокет на несколько IPv4-адресов (на все адреса, имеющиеся у машины), используя `WinSock2`?

Answer (score 4):

Для этого есть специальные константы: `INADDR_ANY` и `in6addr_any` для IPv6.
Подробнее можно почитать: [MSDN bind function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms737550(v=vs.85).aspx)